# Chrome extension is corrupted

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, corrupt

I have problem with my extension. It is working for me unpacked and when I download it from Chrome store.

However, some users reported that after update extension is corrupted. That's happen after they update it to newer version.

Difference between old and new version is background page and some logic.

I was able to replicate that issue, by packing extension and than drop it into extensions tab. After that I saw the same message as extension users. I also tried that with another extensions and everything worked fine, so maybe there is some issue in manifest file.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Cryptocurrency Price Tracker",
    "description": "This simple extension allows you to track price changes of Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies.",
    "version": "2.5",

    "icons": {
               "16":"icon16.png",
               "48":"icon48.png",
               "128":"icon128.png"
     },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "chrome_style": true
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "notifications",
        "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/*"
    ]
}
```

I use background page, not event page. So maybe I should add something in the manifest...

P.S. Packaging doesn't work for older version of extension... One more important thing. Users reported that after clicking on options page they saw that error. It didnt happend in my case, when I drag and drop extension file, I saw error immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in a link to an update url in the manifest. The problem was mentioned in this forum:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/chrome/kGgLwnrDKpQ;context-place=forum/chrome

So you add update_url into your manifest. It can be any valid url if you are not making use of the feature. So like this:

```
"name": "Cryptocurrency Price Tracker",
"description": "This simple extension allows you to track price changes of Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies.",
"version": "2.5",

"icons": {
           "16":"icon16.png",
           "48":"icon48.png",
           "128":"icon128.png"
 },

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
},

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/*"
],
"update_url": "http://www.example.com/update.xml"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to. I saw that but I added different link. With this link it seems to be working. I don't get error message, only cant active extension because it's not from a store. Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that "update_url" is excluded from manifest. You can not use it anymore.